# How to make dependencies of an inline plugin available during run-app in grails 2.1?

Tags: grails, plugins, build

I've modified my app to be a grails plugin, which I'm going to include in client-specific applications and customize some bits and pieces.
To test the whole thing, I've included the plugin as inline in the `BuildConfig` of a test application [bare application created using grails commandline].

```
grails.plugin.location."engine-plugin"="../../engine-plugin"
```

I did not install the plugin itself, I did not add a thing into `plugins` part of the BuildConfig in my app.

Now, in the `BuildConfig` of the plugin, I've included all of the plugins I require in my engine:

```
    compile (
            ":asynchronous-mail:0.6",
            ":famfamfam:1.0.1",
            ":google-visualization:0.5.3",
            ":gsp-arse:1.3",
            ":jquery:1.8.0",
            ":jquery-ui:1.8.15",
            ":mail:1.0",
            ":navigation:1.3.2",
            ":prototype:1.0",
            ":quartz2:0.2.3",
            ":rendering:0.4.3",
            ":spring-security-core:1.2.7.3",
            ":spring-security-ui:0.2"
    )
```

Unfortunately, when I run `grails run-app` in my test app, it can't resolve some classes:

```
4: unable to resolve class grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
 @ line 4, column 1.
   import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
   ^
```

Obviously, that's because my app can't see the `spring-security-core` or it's dependencies.

I've tried changing the scope in my plugin's `BuildConfig` from compile to build, but that changes nothing. I've tried adding `export=true` to it - nothing.

Any tips on how to proceed with this?

Thanks

EDIT:
getting the same error when using the packaged plugin instead of inline :/